# how to get item from certain database variable?

Tags: python, html, django

models.py:

```
class VideoLibrary(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    adress = models.TextField(max_length=264, default='')
```

I have here shop_name and address. The thing I need is to click a button which gets shop_name from text area and match it with address. Is there any way to do it?

[image]

as I mentioned I need to get the name of shop from text area and then show its address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply validate in your form POST view

```
if request.POST.get('shop_name') == request.POST.get('adress'):
    # your code when matched
else
    # throw error
```